Chat model provides answers without source docs
I created embeddings for only one document so far. But when I ask questions which might are in the context but are definitely not part of this single document I would expect an answer like "I cannot find an answer in my knowledgebase". But I am getting a suitable answer which annoys me. I already put in a score filter which is obviously working. So the chain doesnt return any source docs in case it is below the threshold. But I am still getting an suitable answer from its main knowledge - so I believe. I even specify in the prompt that the information shall only be provided from the docs in the vector db but it doesnt have any effect.
Is it possible to change ll/chat model to only use the data stored in the vectordb?
With this code I am creating and storing embeddings:
print("loading embedding model")
model_name = "sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2"
model_kwargs = {'device': 'cpu'}
encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': False}
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name=model_name,
    model_kwargs=model_kwargs,
    encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs
)

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=500,
    chunk_overlap=100
)

print("load file(s) and chunk them")
file_name = "Diplom_Alexa.pdf"
loader = PyPDFLoader(file_name)
docs = loader.load_and_split(
    text_splitter=text_splitter
)
print("create meta data")
for doc in docs:
        doc.metadata = {
            "page": doc.metadata["page"],
            "text": doc.page_content,
            "pdf": file_name
        }
       #print(doc)

print("create embeddings and store them")
db = Chroma.from_documents(
    docs,
    embedding=embeddings,
    persist_directory="emb"
)

With this code I am creating the chat:
llm=CTransformers(model="/home/user/coding/llama2/models/llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin",
                  model_type="llama",
                  config={'max_new_tokens':128,
                          "context_length" : 2048,
                          'temperature':0.1})
llm = Llama2Chat(llm=llm)
print("loading embedding model")
model_name = "sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2"
model_kwargs = {'device': 'cpu'}
encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': False}
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name=model_name,
    model_kwargs=model_kwargs,
    encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs
)

print("setup emebedding database")
db = Chroma(
    persist_directory="emb",
    embedding_function=embeddings
)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True, output_key='result')

prompt_template = """Use the information provided below to answer the question:
Never use your general knowledge only use the informationen provided by the vector store.
if you find an answer provide the source where you found it.
Context from vector database: {context}
Question: {question}
"""

qa_prompt=PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=['context', 'question'])

chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    retriever=db.as_retriever(
        search_type="similarity_score_threshold",
        search_kwargs={'score_threshold': 0.5}
    ),
    memory=memory,
    chain_type="stuff",
    #chain_type_kwargs={'prompt': qa_prompt},
    return_source_documents=True
    #callbacks=[handler]
)

while True:
    user_input=input(f"prompt:")
    
    print(
        boxen(
            user_input,
            title="user input",
            color="cyan",
            padding=1,
            subtitle=datetime.now().strftime("%Y:%m:%d-%H:%M:%S")
        )
    )
    if user_input=='exit':
        print('Exiting')
        sys.exit()
    if user_input=='':
        continue
    result=chain({'query':user_input})
    if result['source_documents']:
        source=result['source_documents'][0]
        source = source.metadata
    else:
        source = "Nothing"
    print(
        boxen(
            f"Answer:{result['result']}\n\nSource: {source}",
            title="ai answer",
            color="yellow",
            padding=1,
            subtitle=datetime.now().strftime("%Y:%m:%d-%H:%M:%S")
        )
    )

Maybe this screenshot helps understanding the problem. That there are no source docs but still a valid answer given.

